# Corona SDK save to image gallery and retrieve it

Tags: coronasdk

I'm new in Corona SDK world, and I'm trying to retrieve a picture from the photo gallery, after that, make some changes to the pictures an then save it again with a new name. I am using the following code:

```
display.save( display.currentStage, { filename="entireScreen.jpg", baseDir=system.DocumentsDirectory, isFullResolution=true } )
```

With this code, I believe I can take all the screen and save it somewhere in the device. Now, the problem is, where is it saved? How can i restore this new picture? I would like to save it in device's photo gallery, is it possible?

Thanks!
RicardoPin.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `display.capture()` function instead of `.save()`, you can do this. Look at the documentation [here](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/display/capture.html). You basically call this function like this:

```
local screenshot = display.capture ( display.currentStage, { saveToPhotoLibrary = true, isFullResolution=true } )
screenshot:removeSelf ()
```

And from the documentation mentioned above:

> `saveToPhotoLibrary` (optional) `Boolean`. If `true`, then it adds the image to your device's photo album (PNG file). For Android devices, you must set the permission level as shown in Gotchas.

Answer (score 0):

The path is /Documents.
On iOS, this information is backed up by syncing.

For more check [Corona Docs](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/system/DocumentsDirectory.html)

To get this picture back,

```
local Img = display.newImage( "entireScreen.jpg", system.DocumentsDirectory, 0, 0 ) .
```

for [more](https://coronalabs.com/blog/2013/02/13/faq-wednesday-sub-folder-and-file-access/)

And this will be in your device's photo gallery